# Combine two JSoup Elements

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using JSoup for the first time to parse the HTML two elements based on class. I am able to successfully pull the data of each. The problem I am having is formatting the data the way I want. The data I am pulling is for a link hit counter.

The final result I want is something like

```
https://yadayadayada.com 1,
https://yadayadayada.com 4,
... etc
```

instead I am getting

```
https://yadayadayada.com https://yadayadayada.com 1, 4,
```

This is how I am getting my current output

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
             Elements links = doc.getElementsByClass("details shorlinkUrl");

             Elements count = doc.getElementsByClass("highlight listUrl").append(",");

             String counter = count.text();
             String linkname = links.text();

             System.out.println(prettyname.toString()+count.toString());

             String results = new StringBuilder(14).append(prettyname).append(counter).toString();
```

Any ideas or direction is greatly apperciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call text() method on Elements object, you get concatenated text from all elements in this collection. You can iterate over separate elements and get text from elements separately and manipulate it accordingly.

```
    Elements links = doc.getElementsByClass("details shorlinkUrl");
    Elements count = doc.getElementsByClass("highlight listUrl");


    if(links.size()!= count.size()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Think about this situation");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< links.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(links.get(i).text() + " " +count.get(i).text()+ ",");
    }
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks